# DBF file type changed to .txt - how do i return to original source

Tags: qgis, dbf

I have opened a dbf file as txt to edit some of the data, now I cannot find the original default programme to open the dbf file with. I tried changing the default programme for the dbf but the QGIS folder has hundreds of options. Can somebody point me to the right programme? Currently, when I open the file in QGIS it appears to have the attribute table beside it as opposed to the icon as usually.

[image]